# Can a components route be set from a file that does not import withRouter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sockets, react-router

**I want to trigger a state change when I recieve endpoint data, in order to syncronize my GUI.**

The file that listens to incoming socket data we will call `sockets.js`. Inside sockets.js I want to call a route transition.

```
if (data === 'gameHasLoaded') { 
  history.push('/game');
}
```

So far so good but...

I am not able to  `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'` because `sockets.js` is in the public folder. Do I have to reconfigure `sockets.js` to be bundled and import react in order to push a route here?

---

**sockets.js**

```
var master = new WebSocket('ws://' + document.domain + ':' + '8000');

function joinQueue(){...};
function leaveQueue(){...};
function rematch(){...};

master.onmessage = function (event) {
    if (data === 'gameHasLoaded') { 
      history.push('/game');
    } else if (data === 'otherEvent') {
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand your requirement and problem. Can you try to clarify your question?

Comment: The problem is that I can not call `history.push('/game')` here because there is no reference to withRouter. I can not import in the file because it is not a react component and it also is not being bundled with react.

Comment: I see. Can you show me the entire code of sockets.js?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara yes. Added to original question

Comment: I hope my answer was sufficient for your question. If it's not, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

Option 1: Use [React-websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-websocket) inside react so you will be able to use `history.push('/game');`
Option 2: Leave everything as is and instead of `history.push('/game');` use `location.href '/game';`

I would prefer to go for option one as with option two you would be reloading the entire page instead leveraging one of the benefits of Single Page Applications

Comment: Thanks! So `sockets.js` does need to be refactored into a component AND I need a helper library to inject websocket as an element? I'm going to give this a shot

Comment: Worked like a charm :-)

Comment: Glad to hear :)